# Archiving Unity app built to Xcode error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.42.0_0' Reader: '800.0.42.1_0')

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, archive

I need to build an iOS app from a Unity app.

Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
Xcode Version: 8.2.1
Unity version 2017.3.1f1
iOS Target: 10.0

Once the Xcode project is generated by Unity, and properly configured to test/deploy in Xcode, I got the following error when archive

```
error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.42.0_0' Reader: '800.0.42.1_0')
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's related to [Xcode 8.2.1 - Error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.41.0_0' Reader: '800.0.42.1_0')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480556/xcode-8-2-1-error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-802-0-41-0-0-reader) but setting "Enable Bitcode" option to "NO" in Target a Project Build settings doesn't solve it...

Furthermore, what is "Producer" and "Reader" value? They should be related with Xcode version but I don't know how to modify it or if it's necessary to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Apple breaks the compatibility between the versions of LLVM Bitcode format from time to time.

The error message says that the version of Clang/LLVM that was used to generate a bitcode is not compatible with the version of Clang/LLVM that attempts to read it.

"Producer" means Clang/LLVM that was used to generate the bitcode, "Reader" means Clang/LLVM that reads that bitcode.

The best thing you can do is to make sure you use the same Xcode i.e. same version of Clang/LLVM to both generate bitcode and then read it. Even better thing is to use the latest Xcode possible (9.2 as of I am writing this).

---

If you cannot upgrade Xcode, and you are trying to hack on the options, then it is not clear why `"Enable Bitcode" option to "NO"` is not working in your case.

> Xcode project is generated by Unity

Does Unity generate some precompiled binaries without letting you compile them with your version of Xcode?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. And yes, the project is generated by Unity, but I don't know if there is any way to modify generated precompiled binaries from Unity.